# How do I display a tiff image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, asp.net-mvc-4

Im totally lost and i need some to guide me. I've seem many post but none explain how can display a tif image. Where can i find some toturial? I need from the begining if posible. Or if you can help me with would it be greate. Im just a newbie halding image.
Im using mvc 4

Comment: How about [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64146/ASP-NET-Multipage-TIFF-Viewer-with-Thumbnails)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most browsers can't handle TIFF images as you've probably found, so you'll need to convert it to a PNG or JPEG. In your controller action, these are the basics.

```
var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("myfile.tif"))
    image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

return File(memoryStream, "image/png");
```

Comment: Yeah, i realized that. Thanks

Comment: It works fine in Windows platform but in cross platform it causes problem. I tried to use this solution but unfortunately had lot of issue which I am still not able to solve due to my server bing on Ubuntu. Here is the details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only