# Show Image in new tab using MVC 4 Actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, devexpress-mvc

There are a lot of articles that Ive read about this, but I havnt found a solution yet.

The situation is simple:

- I have an image hyperlink.
- When clicked, I want the linked file to open in a new tab.
- The file can be a pdf (application/pdf) or a Tif (image/tif).

I have it working with PDF files, but if the file is a TIF image the browser wants to download the file instead of opening in the new tab.

---

here is my controller code:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
    {
        string UploadDirectory = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DealerApplicationFilePath"];
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        string mimeType = "application/unknown";
        switch (fileExtension)
        {
            case ".pdf":
                mimeType = "application/pdf";
                break;
            case ".tif":
                mimeType = "image/tif";
                break;
        }
        var fileStream = new FileStream(UploadDirectory + fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, mimeType);
        //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline"); //Content-Disposition doesnt help.
        return fsResult;
    }
```

---

Here is my chtml code:

```
    Html.DevExpress().HyperLink(settingsBtn =>
    {
        settingsBtn.Name = "cb_" + c.KeyValue.ToString();
        settingsBtn.Properties.Target = "_blank";

            switch (Path.GetExtension(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "FileName").ToString()))
            {
                case ".pdf":
                    settingsBtn.Properties.ImageUrl = "~/Content/GridImages/FileType_PDF.png";
                    break;
                case ".tif":
                    settingsBtn.Properties.ImageUrl = "~/Content/GridImages/FileType_TIF.png";
                    break;
            }

            //This causes a download popup.
            settingsBtn.NavigateUrl = Url.Action("GetFile", "Account", new { fileName = "ATM-311.tif" });

            //This opens in a new tab.
            //settingsBtn.NavigateUrl = Url.Action("GetFile", "Account", new { fileName = "ATM-311.pdf" });
    }).GetHtml();
```

---

and here is the actual HTML tag that gets generated:

```
<a class="dxeHyperlink_Metropolis" id="cb_311" href="/Account/GetFile?fileName=ATM-311.tif" target="_blank"><img src="/Content/GridImages/FileType_TIF.png" alt=""></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15789753/4730201

Comment: Is this behavior consistent across browsers or does it open in a new tab on some browsers but not others?

Comment: @stephen.vakil - it is consistent across browsers (ie, firefox and chrome)

Comment: @RicardoPontual - Thanks Ricardo, your linked helped. I think the post you linked may be correct with its assumption that browsers have trouble dealing with TIF files. As to their solution (using a memorystream and converting the file-type on-the-fly), it does'nt work for me TIF has multiple pages which results in a corruput JPG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong mime type. For `.tif` files, It should be `image/tiff`, not `image/tif`

```
case ".tif":
            mimeType = "image/tiff";
            break;
```

You can replace your entire switch statement code which is errorprone(like this error) by making use of the [`MimeMapping`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/MimeMapping.cs) class which is in the System.Web.

MineMapping has a method called `GetMimeMapping` which will return you the correct mime type based on the file extension.

```
var fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));
```

Comment: Thanks @Shyju. I tried your suggestions but they made no difference. I replaced my mapping with "image/tiff" which didn't make a difference, I then tried using your suggestion of removing the switch and using `MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName)` which also made no difference (still a good suggestion though)

Comment: Are you sure your tif file is valid (not corrupted) ? Are you able to open it in a image viewer app ? I tried the code (with the updated mimeType) and was able to see the image in a new browser tab.

Comment: Thanks @Shyja. The file is valid. It looks like this may be a problem with my browser conf or windows file mappings. It works for other image types but not for a TIF. If I expose the folder and link directly to the file it also results in a download window, which makes me think that this problem is not related to the code itself but to the browser or windows file mappings. I am marking your answer as the correct one as it led me to my conclusion :)